# How to use Find().Select().One() in go mongo-driver library

Tags: mongodb, go

This code is working fine in go mgo library
result interface{}

```
err = getCollection.Find(bson.M{}).Select(bson.M{"_id": 1}).One(&result)
```

but I want to perform this using go mongo-driver library
I have tried below code but it is not working as the above one

```
err = getCollection.FindOne(ctx, bson.M{}, options.FindOne().SetProjection(bson.M{"_id": 1})).Decode(&result)
```

My `test` collection data is

```
example{
"_id":ObjectId(),
"Name":"qwert"
}
```

Anyone suggest me how can we achieve this in mongo-driver?

Comment: Your use of projection is correct.  Does it return the name field in the result? What is the type of `result`? Are you sure the name field was empty before you call this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i can't comment on your question because i am new contributor here, i am using mongo-driver in my project now, i have tried to fetch only projection only some fields to be show up,
can you specific the argument on second for filtering ?

```
var (
   opt options.FindOneOptions
   modelStruct model.Person
)

filter := bson.M{"email": "hello@test.com"}
opt.SetProjection(bson.M{"name": 1})

err := collection.findOne(context.Background(), filter, opt).Decode(&modelStruct)
```

if that doesn't work, then you should limit the struct , make sure in your model.Person has data like this

```
type Person struct {
  Name   string `json:"name" bson:"name"`
  Gender string `json:"gender" bson:"gender"`
}
```

or you can just make own model for limit the fields:

```
var personLimitOnlyGetName struct {
 Name   string `json:"name" bson:"name"`
}

// please look carefully in your collection field for camelCase
opt.SetProjection(bson.M{"name": 1})
```